# Using XML snippets in Maven Polyglot

Tags: java, maven

As a [polyglot maven](https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven) user, I have maven configuration snippet written in xml

For example 
Listing 1. Using maven-jar-plugin to modify MANIFEST.MF

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

taken from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things13/

How can I use it in ,say, my pom.yaml ?

straightforward translation fails

```
$ mvn io.takari.polyglot:polyglot-translate-plugin:translate -Dinput=maven-jar-plugin.xml -Doutput=maven-jar-plugin.yaml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-translating-snippets 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- polyglot-translate-plugin:0.1.15:translate (default-cli) @ maven-translating-snippets ---
[INFO] Translating D:\Workspaces\STS-373\maven-translating-snippets\maven-jar-plugin.xml -> D:\Workspaces\STS-373\maven-translating-snippets\maven-jar-plugin.yaml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.466 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-19T10:00:29+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.takari.polyglot:polyglot-translate-plugin:0.1.15:translate (default-cli) on project maven-translating-snippets: Error translating maven-jar-plugin.xml -> maven-jar-plugin.yaml: Expected root element 'project' but found 'plugin' (position: START_TAG seen \t\t\t<plugin>... @1:11) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: *Expected root element 'project' but found 'plugin'*. Is your POM a valid POM? Looks like it doesn't start with `<project>` and you only have the `<plugin>` element.

Comment: That would require modifying every snippet, and that is exactly what is being asked: translate without modifying.
Because in this example it is just plugin, but some snippets can be plugin configuration or dependency block.

Comment: What snippets? I have never used that plugin but the documentation clearly states that it expects an existing `pom.xml` file, which means that it is a valid `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to migrate my pom.xml using the [official doc](https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven)

I wrote something about how I did it and the problems I encountered [here](https://mikrethor.github.io/blog/blog/2017/maven-polyglot.html)